# Locked ListView or table or something else?

Tags: android, listview, android-layout

I'm trying to build an overview of companies, and I have a problem choosing the way I need to create a layout.
What I want is a (non scrolling) list of items which you can click. Here is an example(of an app that has about what I want):

[image: view example]

So it is the grey list I want.

I have data of all the companies, but some are null. So if I have a string "website" of that company, I want the block of website to appear, and if you click on it the intent to the website starts. And when there is no phone number, I don't want it to appear.

But I'm not clear how to achieve this: should I make a `LinearLayout` or `Table` with buttons, which you set to visible or not? This way probably doesn't work, because it leaves empty holes. Or should I create a `ListView` that doesn't scroll? Than it would be fairly easy to create listItems and make them look like these, but it seems not so logic to create a non scrolling `ListView`.

Or am I missing something really obvious?

Comment: **Custom ListView** with Custom Adapter and setScroll false, Now in your adapter's `getView()` hide the view according to condition Website name or phone number available or not.. Simple :-)

Comment: Note that a list will scroll only if there is not enough space for all the listItems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> should i make a linear layout or table with buttons, which you set to
>   visible or not? This way probably doesn't work, because it leaves
>   empty holes.

=> Instead of View.INVISIBLE, you can also set **View.GONE** which hides a particular view from their position. (Invisible virtually hides the view).

### Update:

I am agree with the comment of **user370305**:

> Custom ListView with Custom Adapter and setScroll false, Now in your
>   adapter's getView() hide the view according to condition Website name
>   or phone number available or not.. Simple :-)

Comment: If some more info provides by you then I will surely go with it. Also It will force me to give +1 to you..

Comment: @user370305 you have already commented with the exact point :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to disable the scroll of your listView

add this on your xml file at ListView

```
android:scrollbars="none"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
listview.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
```